Beppo's plan in "The Adventure of the Six Napoleons"
In 'The Adventure of the Six Napoleons', we see Beppo follow the linear order by which the busts were sold. Morse Hudson, Dr. Barnicot, Horace Harker, Josiah Brown and Sandeford.
He was trying to find the Pearl of the Borgias. He didn't find it in the first three busts (owned by Morse Hudson and Barnicot).
Then he went to Horace Harker's house, who was a journalist. He made a huge commotion in that case, by murdering Pietro Venucci who tracked him there (he was a cutthroat). He had a picture of Beppo, and a map of London. This was major evidence for the entire case, and Beppo was extremely close to his demise.
By following the logical order, he would make himself even more vulnerable, as anyone can go to the manufacturing company and ask for the sales sheet (a record of the people who bought the six busts). He could have went to Sandeford first, broke his bust, and then he would be probably more safe, since Holmes, Lestrade and Watson expected him to be in Josiah Brown's place and not Sandeford's place.
Why didn't Beppo anticipate that the police would be expecting him to steal Mr. Brown's bust, and steal Mr. Sandeford's instead?

I've taken the liberty of adding a question to the post. If I did not guess right, feel free to edit.

Here are four considerations that may go together to explain this aspect of the plot. First, the manager of Harding Brothers reports the following to Holmes:

“Oh, I daresay by consulting our sales book we could very easily tell you. Yes, we have the entries here. One to Mr. Harker you see, and one to Mr. Josiah Brown, of Laburnum Lodge, Laburnum Vale, Chiswick, and one to Mr. Sandeford, of Lower Grove Road, Reading.”

Mr. Brown lives in Chiswick, a suburb of London, while Mr. Sandeford lives in Reading, a city forty miles from London. Therefore, Beppo might reason that if he goes to Chiswick first, which he can easily do using the Metropolitan railway, and gets lucky with Mr. Brown’s bust, then he can save himself the longer journey to Reading.
Second, the police have the resources to do more than one thing at once: they could have placed a constable to watch both the remaining busts, or simply buy the busts and find the pearl for themselves. There was no way for Beppo to know that Holmes would keep his deductions to himself and watch only the Chiswick bust. Remember that Holmes’ secrecy about his deductions is a device to make the story mysterious for the reader, and not something that anyone could reasonably expect.
Third, there is no evidence in the story that Beppo is especially clever. He could, for example, have disguised his purpose by stealing additional objects from Morse Hudson’s shop and Dr. Barnicot’s house, and by discarding the fragments of the broken busts somewhere where they could not be found by the police. No doubt he thought that no-one would connect the breakage of the busts with the pearl.
Fourth, in the Holmes stories, we find that Holmes can reason about the thoughts of the criminals, but we rarely find that criminals can reason about the thoughts of Holmes. Even in ‘The Final Problem’, where Moriarty says that, “All that I have to say has already crossed your mind”, we find that Holmes can deduce that Moriarty would “engage a special” to catch them at Dover, but Moriarty can’t deduce that Holmes would deduce this and change at Canterbury for Newhaven.

Thank you! it was great help for me, and your answer is comprehensive.

(After re-reading the story) The police were pursuing Beppo for the murder - only Homes guessed that there must be something very valuable hidden in one of the busts.

Holmes tells us in the story itself:

There remained two busts, and it was obvious that he would go for the London one first.

Thus, stealing the one in London would seem more logical.
Moreover, regarding

Why didn't Beppo anticipate that the police would be expecting him to steal Mr. Brown's bust

Holmes did a small disinformation campaign, we are told that the newspaper with the piece written by Mr. Horace Harker said:

“It is satisfactory to know that there can be no difference of opinion upon this case, since Mr. Lestrade, one of the most experienced members of the official force, and Mr. Sherlock Holmes, the well-known consulting expert, have each come to the conclusion that the grotesque series of incidents, which have ended in so tragic a fashion, arise from lunacy rather than from deliberate crime. No explanation save mental aberration can cover the facts.

So Beppo could expect that the police was in the dark about his motivations. And, per the initial description at Baker Street, the police (as shown by Lestrade) thought it was someone breaking random busts of Napoleon, not someone breaking busts of Napoleon by Devine from a certain batch. I wouldn't be surprised if that idea was present in the newspaper article as well, although we aren't shown that.

“The Press, Watson, is a most valuable institution, if you only know how to use it.

Finally, do note that we don't know the order in which they were sold. The manager of Gelder & Co simply tells us

the three which had been sent to Morse Hudson a year or so before had been half of a batch of six, the other three being sent to Harding Brothers, of Kensington.

but we don't know if those of Morse Hudson were sent before those of Harding Brothers or not. Beppo does seem to follow the order for the clients of Harding Brothers, though, albeit he probably figured out who those clients were before starting to break the busts (likely during the week since he left Morse Hudson shop), which shows he would probably have used a different order if, say, the first one was out of town.
Beppo got a list of 6 busts, but at the time Sherlock enters into action, 4 of them are already assaulted, so there are only a couple of options left, one of them being in the city and the other out of London.

True! I didn't consider distance to be an important factor. Moreover, I thought that since Beppo had already caught the attention of Holmes and the police, why not try to mislead them into Josiah Brown's place, and go to Sandeford? Holmes would obviously calculate the distance. But another factor is that, at that point, Beppo didn't know much about Holmes.
But, given his job at Morse Hudson's shop, I would say, yeah, he didn't have the financial resources to afford it.
What do you think, if Beppo had been clever, and had more resources, what would be the alternative route to the story?

@AshishMath you only know that as the reader, because we are following Watson account of the story. Beppo doesn't know that. Maybe, had Beppo been aware that Holmes would be following him, what he should have done would be to be quicker (such as entering into the two houses on the same night), as well as starting the actions just before the weekend, so that Holmes (nor the police) wouldn't be able to obtain the list of buyers until Monday, when he would have already finished.

Mr Sandeford lived in Reading, which is some 40 miles from London. The other purchasers of busts lived in the London area. Beppo had no idea which of the busts contained the pearl, so he naturally tried the ones bought by people in London first. He could have gone to Sandeford's house first, but why choose the one furthest away?

Thank you for this intuitive reply!
